# How to Delete Record from Kafka global state store?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

Global state store during restoration will dump the data from the source topic(Which is consider as change-log topic for global-store).

for delete a record i do something like below

```
kvStore.put("key-1",null)
```

how Kafka know's that the record is delete and during restoration it will dump record from source topic (consider source topic has a record with key-1)

In my topology I have

- an input topic -> T1
- and a process is attached that read data from T1 and construct a key from the record and forward down to topic T2
- and topic T2 is a source topic for global state store.

Example:

- T1 i got data: `{"id":'123', "name":"Mohit", "type":"insert"}`
- construct a key for record and forward Down to topic with key and value as T2 -> key: `123` and value: `{"id":'123', "name":"Mohit"}`

After that same key record come as type delete in data.
T1 got data: `{"id":'123', "name":"Mohit", "type":"insert"}`

so i am forward record as like this

```
this.context.forward(key, null)
key: 123 value:null
```

Same is updated in state-store

I just want to know that during restoration with this record will be delete means i get null if i go get on store with key `123`.

Comment: Not 100% sure if I understand the question. However, global stores are read-only and you cannot put/delete data directly (the global processor is only allowed to take the date from the topic as-is to update the store).

Answer (score 1):

State store changelogs are **compacted** topics. To delete a message out of a compacted topic, you ’ll need to do a `put(key, null)` operation. A message with a `null` value is called a **tombstone** and it will *eventually* be deleted by the topic cleaner.

Note, that the message will only be deleted (eventually) in the state store, but not in the input topic.

In the end, the record with key `123` should be removed completely from the state store.

Comment: i am talking about global-state store the use source topic as change-log for him during restoration. 
as data is there in source topic with key:123 it will load the data in global-store

Comment: yes, it will load the data in global state sore, but as the value is "null" it will eventually be deleted from the store.

Comment: I think you have no choise but to put null value in the (compacted) topic.Otherwise it won't be considered in restoration.